# Magento Not Translating Wishlist Product Name and Description

Tags: magento, translation

I have a developmental Magento Store I'm setting up with two languages. Everything works perfect except the SideBar Wishlist and the "My Account" Wishlist displays the Spanish option no matter what. Everything switches i.e. the "My Wishlist" title header, even the email to friend box that automatically writes in "Please, enter your comments..." changes correctly. But the product name and discription remians in Spanish. I've tried this suggestion here: [Wishlist don´t capture store views lenguage](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/280274/)

Has anyone figured out how to fix this or what I might have set incorrectly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem as well on Magento 1.6.2CE. - while switching store languages product names remain in default language.

On a file Wishlist\Model\Item.php arround line 319 you need to remove the line of code:

```
public function getProduct()
{
    $product = $this->_getData('product'); // <-- remove this line
```

The $product object is reloaded again with the correct store filter.

Comment: Liudas looks like you really had the same problem because that worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the scenario, but based on your title I had came up with this.
By any chance, did you manually code the text on a HTML block?

I have came across with this problem, and what I did is find the code snippets where the text is being called. There I changed it with the code below, instead of directly using the text itself. Hope that it makes sense.

```
<?php $this->__('Customers'); ?>
```

Comment: I mean the product description and the product name stay in the second language. Everything on the page will be in English but the Wishlist SideBar product name will be in Spanish. If you go to your account under "My Wishlist" everything will be in English except the product name and description that was set in configuration when you add a new product and then change store views to add your other language. Well, that second language in my case Spanish is what gets displayed in the wishlist ALL THE TIME. :) I figure there is something the matter with Magentos Wishlist function.

Comment: One wouldn't be able to use <?php $this->__('Customers'); ?> because it's your products name and description for each product. The rest like "Customers" changes OK, images change Ok everything changes perfect except the product name and description.